# How to Insert Data from Multiple tables into Single table using Regiseterd Server in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 170 databases with single table having same columns across local network and a central sql server with exact same schema. I want to use Central Management Servers feature of SQL SERVER to get data from all those databases and dump it into central database server.

I don't want to use LINKED SERVER.

Please help?

Comment: use SSIS module

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @sql = CASE WHEN @sql IS NULL 
                 THEN 'SELECT '
                 ELSE @sql + 'UNION ALL SELECT ' END +
              '''' + name + ': '', TABLE_NAME FROM ' + name + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES' +
              CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
   FROM sysdatabases

EXECUTE (@sql)
```

------------SOURCE OF THIS INFO IS----------

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic692117-338-1.aspx

hope this will help.

(* read detail info in the link so you can update according to your scenario)

Comment: My databases are across network. It is not on single instance of sql server and how to save data from those multiples databases table into single table.

Comment: Still searching... any help?